# Getting an error in Xcode that I do not understand

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am brand new to SWIFT/Xcode and I am trying to create a collection view but I keep getting an error when I run my code. The app appears to build successfully but when I select a button that is suppose to take me to a suggested videos screen the app crashes and I get the following error messages. I have seen several SO posts with the same error message but none of the suggested fixes have worked for my implementation. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**Error Messages:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fd6468165e0'
>
> Thread 1: Exception: "-[UIViewController
>   collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fd6468165e0"

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let videoThumbnail = [UIImage(named: "img1"), UIImage(named: "img2"), UIImage(named: "img3"), UIImage(named: "img4"), UIImage(named: "img5"), UIImage(named: "img6")]

    let videoDescription = ["Lorem ipsum 1", "Lorem ipsum 2", "Lorem ipsum 3", "Lorem ipsum 4", "Lorem ipsum 5", "Lorem ipsum 6"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videoThumbnail.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let VideoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

        VideoCell.videoThumbnail.image = videoThumbnail[indexPath.row]
        VideoCell.videoDescription.text = videoDescription[indexPath.row]

        return VideoCell      
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the class of the view controller is not set to `ViewController` but `dataSource` is connected in Interface Builder. The evidence is the base class `UIViewController` in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names you create with UICollectionViewCell (VideoCell) are the same.
try this;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let videoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

        videoCell.videoThumbnail.image = videoThumbnail[indexPath.row]
        videoCell.videoDescription.text = videoDescription[indexPath.row]

        return videoCell      
    }
```